# ant.design <Checkbox.Group/> with mutually exclusive checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

The following component should always only have at most one of the two checkboxes checked. Although the state `checkedList` always only contains at most one value the UI doesn't reflect this state.
What am I missing?

```
interface TeilnehmerProps {
  rolle: Teilnehmerrolle,
  teilnehmer: Teilnehmer,
  readonly: boolean
}

export const TeilnehmerCard = (props: TeilnehmerProps) => {
  const { rolle, teilnehmer, readonly } = props;
  const [name, setName] = useState<string>(teilnehmer?.name);
  const [checkedList, setCheckedList] = useState<CheckboxValueType[]>([teilnehmer?.abwesenheit]);


  const handleChecked = (list: CheckboxValueType[]) => {
    const set = new Set(list);
    if (set.size === 2) {
      set.delete(checkedList[0]);
      setCheckedList(Array.from(set));
    } else if (set.size === 1) {
      setCheckedList(Array.from(set));
    } else {
      setCheckedList([]);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(checkedList);
  }, [checkedList]);

  return <Card title="" size="small" className={styles.teilnehmerCard}>
    <Row key={teilnehmer?.rolle}>
      <Col lg={4}>
        <Form.Item name={`${teilnehmer?.rolle}.abwesenheit`}
                   initialValue={[teilnehmer?.abwesenheit]}>
          <Checkbox.Group value={checkedList}
                          disabled={readonly}
                          options={[{ value: 'ENTSCHULDIGT', label: '' }, { value: 'UNENTSCHULDIGT', label: '' }]}
                          onChange={handleChecked}>
          </Checkbox.Group>
        </Form.Item>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Card>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Once wrapped in `<Form.Item/>` one cannot and shouldn't control the form values anymore, but use `form.setFieldsValue()`.